# Extract values from 2 seprate dataframes with same index and column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes. 
df1:

```
SKU USER 1  USER 2  USER 3  USER 4  USER 5  USER 6  USER 7
1001    5   2   0   0   2   2   1
1002    4   2   2   1   0   1.5 2
1003    1   1   0   0   0   3   3
1004    0   3   0   2   1   0   7
1005    1   1   0   4   4   3.5 0
1006    1   3   4   5   1   3   3
1007    0   1   1   3   0   0   5
1008    2   3   1   0   0   2.333333    0
1009    0   0   0   3   3   0   0
1010    5   6   3   0   2   4   6
```

df2:

```
SKU USER 1  USER 2  USER 3  USER 4  USER 5  USER 6  USER 7
1001    7.398414    4.398414    2.398414    2.398414    4.398414    4.398414    3.398414
1002    6.321304    4.321304    4.321304    3.321304    2.321304    3.821304    4.321304
1003    3.535435    3.535435    2.535435    2.535435    2.535435    5.535435    5.535435
1004    2.865097    5.865097    2.865097    4.865097    3.865097    2.865097    9.865097
1005    3.152332    3.152332    2.152332    6.152332    6.152332    5.652332    2.152332
1006    2.816583    4.816583    5.816583    6.816583    2.816583    4.816583    4.816583
1007    2.378649    3.378649    3.378649    5.378649    2.378649    2.378649    7.378649
1008    4.431189    5.431189    3.431189    2.431189    2.431189    4.764522    2.431189
1009    2.196257    2.196257    2.196257    5.196257    5.196257    2.196257    2.196257
1010    7.148196    8.148196    5.148196    2.148196    4.148196    6.148196    8.148196
```

I want to print the actual (df1) and predicted (df2) for each USER-SKU combination as follows:

For  `USER1 SKU 1001: ACTUAL = 5, PREDICTED = 7.398414`

How can I extract these values"?

Comment: So you want a function that returns the matches on SKU and USER 1 in both dfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be [pivoted](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html). It is easier to work with in this case, if you first [unpivot (melt)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) the data back to a table of `(sku, user, value)` rows and then merge the 2 tables to form a table of `(sku, user, actual, predicted)` rows.

```
import pandas as pd

# Reset indexes for unpivoting. If you need the original DataFrames
# as is later on, don't pass inplace=True and store the return value as
# the new index free frame.
df1.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

# unpivot dataframes
df1_melt = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['SKU'], var_name='USER', value_name='ACTUAL')    
df2_melt = pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['SKU'], var_name='USER', value_name='PREDICTED')

# merge dataframes on SKU, USER
df_merged = df1_melt.merge(df2_melt, on=['SKU', 'USER'])

for row in df_merged.itertuples(index=False):
    sku, user, actual, predicted = row
    print('{user} SKU {sku}: ACTUAL = {actual}, PREDICTED = {predicted}'.format(
        user=user, sku=sku, actual=actual, predicted=predicted
    ))
```

Comment: I ran this and get a KEY ERROR for SKU

Comment: Is `SKU` an index in your dataframes?

Comment: @Anu updated the answer to reset indexes in case your data frames are using SKU as such.

Comment: SKU is an index in my dataframe. I still get the KeyError: 'SKU'.

Comment: How does your `df1.columns` look like after the `df1.reset_index(inplace=True)`? I've composed the code using your examples of df1 and df2, both using "SKU" as index and not. The `KeyError` just indicates that your dataframes lack a column named SKU before and after index reset, so it probably just has a slightly different name.

Comment: Yes, it is running perfect now. I added a line df1.index.name = 'SKU' before unpivot and it worked. Thank you Ilja  for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to rename your columns, I believe you can just use loops and simple indexing as follows:

```
cols = range(7)
for c in cols:
    column = "USER " + str(c + 1)
    rows = range(10)
    for r in rows:
        actual = df1.iloc[r,c]
        predict = df2.iloc[r,c]
        print str(column) + "SKU" + str(r + 1001) + ": ACTUAL= " + str(actual) + ", PREDICTED = " + str(predict)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This has run successfully, thank you so much! I am trying Ilja's approach as well as I feel I need the merged data frame for further calculations.

Comment: done! I was just new to stackoverflow, and was not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to rename the columns in `df2` and then `merge` and then define a lookup function:

```
In [175]:    
df2.rename(columns=d_cols,inplace =True)
df2.columns

Out[175]:
Index(['SKU', 'PRED USER 1', 'PRED USER 2', 'PRED USER 3', 'PRED USER 4',
       'PRED USER 5', 'PRED USER 6', 'PRED USER 7'],
      dtype='object')

In [184]:
df3 = df1.merge(df2)
def lookup(sku):
    return 'USER1 SKU {:d}: ACTUAL = {:f}, PREDICTED = {:f}'.format(sku, df3.loc[df3['SKU'] == sku, 'USER 1'].values[0], df3.loc[df3['SKU']==sku,'PRED USER 1'].values[0])
df3['SKU'].apply(lookup).iloc[0]

Out[184]:
'USER1 SKU 1001: ACTUAL = 5.000000, PREDICTED = 7.398414'
```